# How to execute flyway scripts upon starting nodejs project?

Tags: node.js, spring-boot, database-migration, flyway

I was using Flyway with SpringBoot and I loved the experience. Everything worked OOTB and scripts were executed upon boot.

I moved to project where we use node.js, typescript and graphql. I would like to use flyway in the same way like in Spring Boot, i.e.

- Place SQL scripts within project
- Execute scripts upon starting the server

What would be the way to go?

Comment: Would love to know if you came up with a solution for this?
I am in the same predicament.

Comment: Hi Melissa,
I have extended package.json with a commend "db:migrate" so that know I can run "npm run db:migrate" 

Afterwords, I have extended run script to first execute the migration commend and afterwards to start the nodejs server. So when I write "npm run start", that internally executes db migration

Comment: Hi @Hola. Ah ok ... I assume that your db:migrate in package.json then includes a flway cli command?  So the machine you running on must have flyway cli installed?

Comment: Exactly. In my settings, I already have Docker, so I start a flyway container